# Kubuntu 16.04 login trouble

Tags: kubuntu, login, lightdm, systemd, symbolic-link

My system has a **Radeon 9250** card for graphics, and an AMD Athlon 3000+ 64-bit CPU.
The motherboard is from Asus and it's an K8V SE Deluxe.
I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.1 and all was well for a week, but then the trouble started.
I removed sddm because it was conflicting with lightdm, and since then I am stuck in lightdm.
When I type my password nothing happens.

I can login in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+F1-6), and these are things I already tried.
Checked the ownership of the ~.Xautorithy file.
Then I ran the following command:

```
systemctl enable displaymanager.service
```

Wich resulted in this:

```
---AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedsektop.system1.manage-unit-files---

Authentication is requirred to manage system or unit files.  
Authentication as: my name  
Password: my password

---AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE---

Failed to execute operation: too many levels of symbolic links.
```

Then I ran this command:

```
ls -l /etc/lightdm/*
```

I got these results:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.config

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.config~
```

I tried to remove the configuration files by purging lightdm but without succes.

Then I did the following:

```
sudo lightdm -c /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Wich gave me this output:

```
Failed to use bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager, do you have appropriate permissions ?
```

I there a way I can fix this ?

I also remember an error about Dbus when I ran journalctl.

This happend around 21th of August, and I did not find a solution here or anywhere else.

I want to solve this without having to do a fresh install, because I have seen alot off people with the same problem.

Thank you for any help I can get.

I never have never dealt with the init system in all the 12 years I use Linux, so I do not know anything about it.

**Is there anybody who can help me ?**

Comment: My system has a Radeon 9250 card for graphics.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's better to [edit] additional info into your question as comments can be deleted for any number of reasons (and not everyone reads them), I'll do it for you this time.